# search filter by date in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make a search filter by date but i get an error.
 This is my Search method:

```
   public ActionResult Search(DateTime StartDate,DateTime EndDate)
    {
        var result = (
            from r in context.Rooms
            from v in context.Reservations
                .Where(a =>a.Room_ID == r.RoomID
                    &&
                    !(
                        StartDate >= a.Data_Check_out ||
                        EndDate <= a.Data_Check_in
                    )
                    && a.Cancel == false
                ).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where v.ReservationID == null
            select r
            );
        return View(result);
    }
```

And here is my View:

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication4.Models.Room>

             @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Room", FormMethod.Get)) 
            { 
           @Html.TextBox("StartDate") 
           <input type="submit" value="Search" /> 
         @Html.TextBox("EndDate") 
         <input type="submit" value="Search" /> }
          @foreach (var x in Model)
          {
         <div class="item">
         <h1>@x.Room_Type.Room_Type1</h1>

        </div>}`
```

I get the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'StartDate' of non-nullable type 'System.DateTime' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Search(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' in 'MvcApplication4.Controllers.RoomController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
>   Parameter name: parameters`

Comment: How are you posting to the server? with the submit button or with ajax? And you should use `TextBoxFor`. Not sure it will help you though.

Comment: It looks like you're providing a link to that action in another view without passing it those two date parameters. Check your usage.

Comment: Are you using a date format other than the American format, MM/dd/yyyy?

Comment: no i am using the american format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you are passing the parameters in url? If not then its better to use model in your controller to fetch value. This error is coming because controller is not able to get the parameter values.

Comment: Go through this article :- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-view-controller-Step-by-Step-in-7 Actually you need to access model in controller which will return values to you or even you can access your view textboxes using Request.Form["StartDate"].ToString()